# How to time the database backup of a production db for trace replay?

Tags: sql-server-2019, trace

I am exploring the SQL trace replay feature.

My IT admin has given me a replica of the production SQL server (without network access) to perform some testing. I intend to perform the patching and config changes on this new server and then replay the trace captured from the production SQL server.

I understand that I need to restore the database backup on this new server and they replay the trace via SQL profiler.

I will explain my concern with an example:

1. Say I take the database backup
2. New row is added to the Product table
3. I start capturing the trace now
4. New row is added to the sales table that references the Product added at step 2.
5. Other CRUD queries get executed..
6. Stop trace

Now when I restore the above database onto the new server, it will not have the Product record from step 2. So when I replay the trace, the command to insert the new sales record (step 4) will fail as the database is missing the corresponding value in product table.

How are such issues to be handled (or timed) when working with replaying trace? For example - do I ask for downtime on the moment when I am about to start taking the database backup, and start capturing the trace?

Comment: If you are taking routine Transaction Log backups (e.g. every 5 minutes), then the chances of that kind of issue happening are small. You should start the trace closest to your last backup.

Answer (score 1):

> How are such issues to be handled (or timed) when working with replaying trace?

Either tolerate a few errors due to slightly different data, or also get a few transaction log backups containing the LSN of the full backup and restore the database to the point-in-time before you started the trace.

You can use STOPAT with restore to either a timestamp or a [log mark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#marked-transactions).

Comment: The error will cause trace to stop or it will run anyways?

Comment: That depends on your replay tool.

Comment: Sql profiler is the replay tool.